# Embed .net binary in a native executable

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, security, native

Is there a way to embed my .net executable (C#/VB.Net) in a ntive binary like a C/C++ file which will load the .net assembly on startup?
Like building a native wall arround the .net assembly?

Comment: Do you want to run it without a .NET FW installed or whats the purpose of this?

Comment: If you mean a mixed assembly? See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx)

Comment: @chrfin : No, it wshould still require the FW. The reason is to improve the security.

Comment: Can you explain where a mixed assembly would help with security? I *think* you are on the wrong trail here, as IMO managed assemblies are more secure...

Comment: Maybe it isn't using for security issue, Obfuscation is for that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Answer (score 3):

You could embed your .Net binary in the C++ project as a resource and load it runtime, but I doubt that is a recommended way to increase security.

Edit:
Someone asked for source code and suggested that I make a comment instead of an answer. I've just signed up for StackOverflow and I don't have enough reputation to make comments yet.
But here's some source I used at some point:

```
    public static int RunInternalExe(byte[] rawData, params string[] args)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.Load(rawData);
        MethodInfo mi = asm.EntryPoint;

        if (mi == null)
            throw new Exception("Entry point not found");

        ParameterInfo[] prms = mi.GetParameters();

        object[] mtd_args = null;
        if (prms.Length > 0)
            mtd_args = new object[] { args };

        object result = mi.Invoke(null, mtd_args);

        if (result is int)
            return (int)result;

        return 0;
    }
```

Embed the managed .exe in your wrapper .exe and pass the raw data to the proc above.

```
MyTools.RunInternalExe(Resources.ExeData);
```

Ofcourse, if you want your wrapper .exe to be non-managed you'd have to translate the code above to C++ or some other language of your choice, that's kind of above my head right now...

Comment: How, exactly? The Windows loader requires loadable binaries (either .exe or .dll) to be real on-disk files.

Comment: Not .NET executables, they are not loaded by the Windows loader.  Assembly.Load(byte[]) is supported.  Bad idea.

Comment: It would help if you added links to external resources, perhaps even some source code, to add credibility to your answer. Right now it really stands better as a comment.